# Get a COUNT based on a date when the column is a timestamp in a T-SQL query?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get a count based on a date but the column is a timestamp. I think I need to place the cast function after the FROM statement but not sure.

```
Select Count(X), Cast(Y as date)
From table
Where Y = '2019-04-01';
```

I have tried a bunch of derivatives of the above query, I have gotten some of the queries to run but still haven't been able to get actual output. I can't seem to find a good example on the Google, so I thought someone on here may have run into this issue. `TO_CHAR` and `TRUNK` are not supported.

Current code:

```
SELECT COUNT([X]), CAST(Y AS date)
FROM table
WHERE Y = '04/01/2019'
GROUP BY Y ORDER BY Y;
```

Runs, but returns no output (I know there are results).

---

```
SELECT COUNT([email]), processed
FROM [AJM].[dbo].[EmailSend]
CAST(processed AS date)
WHERE processed = '04/01/2019'
```

Group by processed order by processed;

Error:

> "processed" is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a parameter to a table-valued function or to the CHANGETABLE function, ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90.

The goal is to get a count of X or Y by the date specified.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running for compatibility level 90 to be referenced? That's SQL Server 2005.

Comment: As for your latter SQL, you're missing the keyword `WHERE`. If you're passing dates, use unambiguos formats. Those are `yyyyMMdd` and `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.sssssss` for SQL Server. For the first SQL, `2019-04-01` might be interpreted as 01 April or 04 January, depending on your language/datatype and the same for `'04/01/2019'`.

Comment: when you say the field is a Timestamp, do you mean the type TIMESTAMP?  If it is it isn't really a date, it's more like a random key, the name is misleading.

Comment: Also, do your value of `Y` have a time component in their values (not `00:00:00.000`)?

Comment: @Cato raises a good point. `timestamp` is an alias for `rowversion`, which is a `binary` value, not a date and time.

Comment: One you need to do is stop using random strings for dates. You have at least two different string literals representing dates in your post. You should always use the ANSI compliant YYYYMMDD. It is the only string literal that will always works regardless of local settings.

Comment: I'm not working in T-SQL (I usually do)...so I don't know why the admin changed my question. I'm working with MS SQL.

Answer (score 0):

do you need something like the following?

```
SELECT COUNT([email]), processed
FROM [AJM].[dbo].[EmailSend]
WHERE CAST(processed AS date) = '04/01/2019'
```

Comment: missing out on the question mark in your answer... If so.. its not an answer... and you know what happens ;p

Comment: Thanks Cato!! Such a simple adjustment...I was probably so close to this!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing a date and a timestamp, you probably won't have much luck.  Try the following:

```
SELECT COUNT([X]), CAST(Y AS date)
FROM table
WHERE Y = CAST('2019-04-01' as TIMESTAMP)
GROUP BY Y ORDER BY Y;
```

By casting the right side instead of left, you can still take advantage of indexing.

Comment: A `timestamp` doesn't have anything to do with a specific date and time.

Comment: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=054e738cb6de2cf245bf28446d8c032b) to show that `timestamp` <> Date and Time value.

Comment: This just isn't ever going to work like this at all. But you also have some valid points in here regarding SARGability and the inability to compare the timestamp and datetime data types.

Comment: I'm assuming that since date and timestamp are completely incompatible (which I did mention at the beginning), and since the questioner said "I did get some of the queries to run", most likely we are talking about date / datetime or date / datetimeoffset or something similar, for which what I wrote above would work (obviously not directly as timestamp).  It was meant to be a gently guide into finding the solution....